# Derivative of the unit normal vector and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be an embedded surface with induced Euclidean metric and $p \in M$. Let $N$ be the unit normal vector filed over $M$. Let $v \in T_pM$ be any of unit length. Consider any curve $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. In textbooks, we define the vector
$$\nabla_v N:= \dfrac{d}{dt} N(\gamma(t))(0),$$and call it the derivative of $N$ in the $v$ direction at $p$.

My question: do we have any relation between $|\nabla_v N|$ and the curvature of the curve $\gamma$ at $p$? I guess that these two are equal.

Assume here that $\gamma$ has unit speed so the curvature of $\gamma$ at $p$ is $|\gamma''(0)|$.

Comment: Have you tried calculating this for various circles on a sphere?

Comment: @Ted By your suggetion, now I saw that these two are not equal for any curve, but they are equal if $\gamma$ lies in the intersection between $M$ and  the plane spaning by $v$ and $N$ .

Comment: Aha. Good. So now look at normal curvature of a curve on a surface!

Comment: @Ted Can you write more about your suggestion? The normal curvature of a curve is the component of the acceleration in the normal direction.

Comment: Yes, assuming arclength parametrization. You should show that the normal curvature of $\gamma$ at $p$ is the answer. :) If you don't figure it out, look at my differential geometry text, linked in my profile :)

Comment: @Ted I could verify the last fact that I mentioned (when $\gamma$ is in the intersection). I though you would offer me some another interseting intuition behind this :). Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's more general than that, as I indicated. For such a curve, the curvature at $p$ is the normal curvature. But my claim holds for all curves.

Comment: @Ted After a while, I was not able to check your claim, that is I didn't see that the normal curvature $k_n$ of $\gamma$ at $p$ is equal to the norm of $\nabla_v N$ at $p$. I can only see that $k_{n}=\pm\left\langle \nabla_{v}N,v\right\rangle $.